# AWS Cloudfront - How to avoid caching instead of TTL in Browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-cloudfront, cdn, browser-cache

we are using Elastic Beanstalk (NodeJS Script) and Cloudfront to deliver a JS File to our Clients.

We send a new version number with each new release and track the requests. We noticed that we sometimes have queries with old version numbers in our database for weeks.

We use the AWS Cloudfront Invalidation of course, but this does not seem to have cleared the problem because the version is in the browser's cache. How can we ideally solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer to this is to add versions to the end of the JS file request. For example

```
<script src="https://example.com/js/myfile.js?v=1"></script>
```

With each update you would also update the variable

```
<script src="https://example.com/js/myfile.js?v=2"></script>
```

etc.

Other options are to set cache control headers on the file itself, telling it to not cache etc but this relies on the browser to honor that and is not always exact, by adding the query variable the browser / cdn will think the file is new and re-download.

This does require that your CDN honors querystrings when caching too though, as some will drop the query string etc.

Comment: Thanks for your Feedback! Our Script is placed in more as 900 Websites, so each Partner has to change the Script with version. This will not work for us, but indeed in general the perfect idea.

Comment: Then the best option would be to set the cache-control header to 'Cache-Control: no-cache' (this assumes the JS file is downloaded from your server and you can control the headers) This would tell the browser not to cache this file and would request a new version each time the page is loaded up.